# Dimension of subspace $W$ of vector space $V$ for infinite-dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider a subspace $W$ of a vector space $V$ (*not* necessarily finite-dimensional). I know that if $V$ was finite-dimensional, we can prove that $\dim W \le \dim V$. Does this hold even when $V$ is not finite-dimensional? If so, then do we have to assume some form of the Axiom of Choice to prove this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the axiom of choice, yes. If $W$ is a subspace of $V$, choose a basis of $W$, and extend it to a basis of $V$; now recall that the cardinality of a basis is unique, even for infinite-dimensional spaces, and that is enough to finish the argument.

Without the axiom of choice, however, there is no real notion of dimension anymore. It is possible for a space to have two bases of different cardinalities, or a space with a basis will have a subspace without a basis, etc.

Comment: I'd forgotten that without the axiom of choice, the concept of dimension doesn't make sense. Thanks!